# Using Conan to install packages directly from GitHub

Tags: c++, c, package-managers, conan

Following [this feature request](https://github.com/ProGTX/clinfo/issues/1#issue-634544268), there are some Conan packages hosted on [Bincrafters GitHub organization](https://github.com/bincrafters):

1. [Conan package for OpenCL Headers](https://github.com/bincrafters/conan-khronos-opencl-headers)
2. [Conan package for Khronos OpenCL CLHPP](https://github.com/bincrafters/conan-khronos-opencl-clhpp)
3. [Conan package for OpenCL ICD Loader](https://github.com/bincrafters/conan-khronos-opencl-icd-loader)

I tried searching them on the command line with `conan search <packageName>` using different queries with no avail. I'm not sure how Conan package manager works. With HomeBrew one could tap different repositories or with pip directly install from a GitHub repository. I would appreciate it if you could help me know how I can install the above packages and how my `conanfile.txt` should look like.

**P.S.1.** Sorry in advance if the tags are not appropriate. I wasn't sure what should I use, so feel free to edit and add or remove them.

**P.S.2.** Possible solution from [here](https://bincrafters.github.io/2017/06/06/using-bincrafters-conan-repository/), running

```
conan remote add bincrafters https://api.bintray.com/conan/bincrafters/public-conan
```

now I can find the above packages with

```
conan search -r bincrafters khronos-opencl-icd-loader
conan search -r bincrafters khronos-opencl-icd-loader
```

and my `conanfile.txt` should look something like:

```
[requires]
khronos-opencl-headers/20190806@bincrafters/stable
khronos-opencl-icd-loader/20191007@bincrafters/stable

[generators]
cmake
```

Comment: Could your please elaborate which commands did you run? Including the entire command line of course.  The command `conan search -r bincrafters khronos-opencl-headers` works for me, running Conan 1.25.2

Comment: If a Bincrafters' package is not listed in Conan Center, you can check the Bintray page directly: https://bintray.com/bincrafters/public-conan. Anyway, `conan search` should be enough for any search. Also, `khronos-opencl-headers/20190806@bincrafters/stable` is the most recent reference to be add in your conanfile.txt. Please, read https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile_txt.html to get more info.

Comment: @uilianries apologies for the late reply. tried the `conan search -r ...` command and got `ERROR: No remote 'bincrafters' defined in remotes`

Comment: @uilianries check **P.S.2.**

Comment: Bincrafters is not a default remote, you need to add it manuallly, only Conan Center is listed by default. To add Bincrafters: `conan remote add bincrafters  https://api.bintray.com/conan/bincrafters/public-conan`. Please, read this to get more info: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/uploading_packages/remotes.html#bincrafters