# CMake detects a wrong version of OpenCL

Tags: c, windows, cmake, opencl, nvidia

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62251277/4999991), where I have used [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62193875/4999991) to install NVIDIA's OpenCL SDK. The `clinfo` tool detects a 1.2 OpenCL version correctly. However, The below `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(OpenCL_Example)

find_package(OpenCL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${OpenCL_LIBRARY})

add_executable(main main.c)
target_include_directories(main PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(main ${OpenCL_LIBRARY})
```

copied from [here](https://streamhpc.com/blog/2015-09-25/handling-opencl-with-cmake-3-1-and-higher/), detects the wrong version of OpenCL 1.1 :

```
-- Looking for CL_VERSION_1_1 - found
-- Found OpenCL: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v3.2/lib/Win32/OpenCL.lib (found version "1.1")
```

I would appreciate it if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can resolve it.

**P.S.1.** you may use the below dummy `main.c` C code just for testing

```c
#include <CL/cl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World! \n");
    return 0;
}
```

**P.S.2.** Following [this Tweet](https://twitter.com/sci_vision/status/1270133916616339457?s=20), I ran the `cmake .. --debug-find` command and got [this log](https://pastebin.com/x73teT3M). But still not sure what is the problem.

**P.S.3.** Following [this Tweet](https://twitter.com/sci_vision/status/1270293828000415745?s=20), it turns out that I had installed [a very outdated CUDA toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-32-downloads). Uninstalling that, now I get

> -- Found OpenCL: C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/system_studio_2020/OpenCL/sdk/lib/x86/OpenCL.lib (found version "2.2")

which is Intel's SDK. It was basically the second result on [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&sxsrf=ALeKk02UDtPI2RQYxPqjG0oA5gfZ2WxiTQ%3A1591701354243&source=hp&ei=am_fXsOdDM_3kwXc_o-oBg&q=nvidia%20opencl%20sdk%20download&oq=nv&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgAMgQIIxAnMgQIIxAnMgQIIxAnMgUIABCRAjIFCAAQkQIyBAgAEEMyBAgAEEMyBAgAEEMyBAgAEEMyBAgAEEM6AggAUIokWMolYNwuaABwAHgAgAFkiAHCAZIBAzEuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab) " NVIDIA OpenCL SDK download", firstly being completely confusing. So I had to uninstall it and install the latest version from here. NVIDIA could at least mention that one has to install CUDA toolkit to get the OpenCL SDK!

Comment: Did you try specifying the exact version when calling `find_package()`? e.g.: `find_package(OpenCL 1.2 EXACT REQUIRED)`

Comment: @squareskittles thanks for the comment. It is actually a bad practice to specifify the exact version of the SDK/SPI/Platfrom but for the sake of debuging the issue, It added the above command and got the `Could NOT find OpenCL: Found unsuitable version "1.1", but required is exact version "1.2"` error.

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be bad practice, especially when you have multiple versions of the same software located on the machine. You can view the [Version Selection](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#version-selection) section of the `find_package()` documentation, which describes how CMake picks a version in different situations. Its ability to find the version you want varies by package, and relies on a version file (`opencl-config-version.cmake`) being present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NVidia Cuda v3.2` was released according to [this](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive) on Nov 2010 and `OpenCL 1.2` spec was released one year later on November 15, 2011. So I suspect `cmake` is detecting `OpenCL 1.1` correctly.

If you have another SDK installed and you want `cmake` to detect `OpenCL 1.2` despite having another SDKs supporting older version you need to specify that information in `cmake`. Otherwise it will find the first `OpenCL` on the search path and stop. So it should be specified `find_package(OpenCL 1.2 REQUIRED)` or as @squareskittles pointed `find_package(OpenCL 1.2 EXACT REQUIRED)` if you want exact version.

However you may need to add other SDKs paths to PATH or specify them in `cmake` so that it has a chance to examine other `OpenCL` versions. If you have a look at `find` `cmake` macros content they contain some typical search paths specified and if you have SDK installed in other not standard path you have to tell that cmake yourself. That is especially the case on `Windows` where you don't have standard more specific install paths  for includes or libraries like for example on `Linux`. On `Windows` there is really `Program Files` but that is too generic and cmake would have to search through it recursively and I'm not sure if that is even supported.

I suspect you may have `nvidia cuda 3.2 toolkit` path added to PATH only or you specified that path in cmake only. So here would the problem lie. Adding other SDKs paths may resolve the issue.

Also I think `clinfo` checks runtime `OpenCL` installations meaning it can be any vendor `OpenCL.dll` which supports OpenCL 1.2 on your NVidia GPU and `cmake` checks in SDK's header which `OpenCL` version your installed SDK supports. So here can be the discrepancy. In this case you may need to install newer cuda toolkit.

Comment: check **P.S.3.** please.